# Should Desktop-Extension: Running in background or Shutting down?

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I have an UWP app with a background Desktop extension which performs task, sometimes it will be unused for hours, sometimes it will be needed every few seconds. I need to know if when it is not running, should it be shut down with `Application.Current.Shutdown()` or simply left running and wait for the next `RequestReceived`? I dont want to waste ressources, but it seems like an inactive Desktop Extension takes up minimal resources, right?

The only issue with shutting it down is performance: The UWP app needs to wait for a response, so is there a performance difference between starting the component and sending the request vs just sending the request?

Either way, what is considered best practice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desktop extension background process is only used to handle requests from your UWP foreground app, then the best practice would be to link its lifetime to the state of your foreground app. You can control it from UWP by sending a message to your extension to shut itself down when the UWP goes into a state where the extension is no longer needed (e.g. when it gets suspended).

In general it is good practice for the extension to shut itself down when the AppService connection gets closed. You can do this by listening to the ServiceClosed event on the AppServiceConnection instance in your extension. I have an example posted here ("Handle Process Exit - scenario #2) : https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/

Comment: I should have mentioned that the UWP app is supposed to run in the background too most of the time. What is the best solution then?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "running in the background"? If you are suspended in the taskbar then you won't need the extension to be running and might as well shut it down. Another (maybe simpler) way to do is to listen to the ServiceClosed event on the AppServiceConnection in your extension and then shut yourself down. I have explained this some more here ("Handling Process Exit" - scenario #2): https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/

Comment: I mean something like ShareX or GestureSign are doing, they have a background process that is triggered by a Hotkey or another action. In my case, my UWP component is waiting for selected apps to be in Focus and will trigger in this case.

Comment: What happens if the UWP is not running when the action triggers? Nothing - or do you launch it from your desktop extension?

Comment: I am using <rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime"/>  so the UWP part is running in background all the time. When the action triggers, the desktop extension is required to do an action, but none show an user interface.

Comment: In that case you are already running all the time anyway, so keeping the extension running seems ok. At any rate, I would recommend shutting it down though when the AppServiceConnection is closed - if only to avoid ending up with multiple (orphaned) desktop extension processes running.